# MSMQ and 64-bit Dependent Clients?

Tags: msmq

We're in the process of upgrading servers to 64-bit versions of the windows operating system. We encountered the "msmq dependent clients cannot be installed on 64-bit computers" issue the other day. I have found a few documents that state this as fact but they are all fairly old.

Do the newest versions of MSMQ for Windows Server 2008 support 64-bit dependent clients ?

If not, why not ?

From what I have read, you can still configure MSMQ dependent client functionality by clicking in the right places but I don't see why the 32 or 64 bit platform would matter.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent Clients are deprecated as Microsoft wants you to move away from using them although there are certain scenarios where they can be useful. Support will not improve for DCs. If you are trying to use MSMQ 4.0 clients (Windows Vista/2008 R1) and above then you are out of luck as you have found : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732702(v=ws.10).aspx.

I can't find a definitive reason why 64-bit doesn't have the dependent client code in it.

[Still using MSMQ 2.0? Better start planning as 2010 is not far away.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/01/21/still-using-msmq-2-0-better-start-planning-as-2010-is-not-far-away.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you getting that error, and when, and where ?

We run a variety of MSMQ-enabled servers, all flavours, both 32-bit and 64-bit, and I have never seen that error.

Comment: We don't receive an error. It's just that the 'local storage' option does not show up so it can't be unselected which makes it impossible to configure it as a dependent client.